# How to select a region of an image in bokeh

Tags: bokeh

In a web app, I would like to let the user select a region of interest in a plotted image using the nice box/lasso selection tools of bokeh. I would the like to receive the selected pixels for further operations in python.

For scatter plots, this is easy to do in analogy with the [gallery](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/selection_histogram.py),

```
import bokeh.plotting
import numpy as np

# data
X = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
def f(x): return np.random.random(len(x))

# plot and add to document
fig = bokeh.plotting.figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10),
    tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_select,lasso_select,reset")
plot = fig.scatter(X, f(X))
#plot = fig.image([np.random.random((10,10))*255], dw=[10], dh=[10])
bokeh.plotting.curdoc().add_root(fig)

# callback
def callback(attr, old, new):
    # easily access selected points:
    print sorted(new['1d']['indices'])
    print sorted(plot.data_source.selected['1d']['indices'])
    plot.data_source.data = {'x':X, 'y':f(X)}
plot.data_source.on_change('selected', callback)
```

however if I replace the scatter plot with

```
plot = fig.image([np.random.random((10,10))*255], dw=[10], dh=[10])
```

then using the selection tools on the image does not change anything in `plot.data_source.selected`.

I'm sure this is the intended behavior (and it makes sense too), but what if I want to select pixels of an image? I could of course put a grid of invisible scatter points on top of the image, but is there some more elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the tool you're looking for is actually the [BoxEditTool](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#boxedittool). Note that the BoxEditTool requires a list of glyphs (normally these will be [Rect](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/rect.html) instances) that will render the ROIs, and that listening to changes should be set using:

```
rect_glyph_source.on_change('data', callback)
```

This will trigger the `callback` function any time you make any changes to your ROIs.

The relevant ColumnDataSource instance (`rect_glyph_source` in this example) will be updated so that the 'x' and 'y' keys list the center of each ROI in the image's coordinates space, and of course 'width' and 'height' describe its size. As far as I know there isn't currently a built-in method for extracting the data itself, so you will have to do something like:

```
rois = rect_glyph_source.data
roi_index = 0 # x, y, width and height are lists, and each ROI has its own index

x_center = rois['x'][roi_index]
width = rois['width'][roi_index]
y_center = rois['y'][roi_index]
height = rois['height'][roi_index]

x_start = int(x_center - 0.5 * width)
x_end = int(x_center + 0.5 * width)
y_start = int(y_center - 0.5 * height)
y_end = int(y_center + 0.5 * height)

roi_data = image_plot.source.data['image'][0][y_start:y_end, x_start:x_end]
```

---

**IMPORTANT**: In the current version of Bokeh (0.13.0) there is a problem with the synchronization of the BoxEditTool at the server and it isn't functional. This should be fixed in the next official Bokeh release. For more information and a temporary solution see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743494/bokeh-edittools-callback-to-server/51829785#51829785) or [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/bokeh/UuWpZJfE1Z0/pQ5c5QHxDgAJ).